# Ensure ordered shutdown of bundles in karaf

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, blueprint-osgi

For a simple use-case, I have two bundles in Karaf as:

1. Bundle-Shared-Library
2. Bundle-My-Implementation -> depends on (1) Bundle-Shared-Library, mentioned in blueprint via `depends-on` attribute of the bean

Steps that I am following:

1. Load Bundle(1)
2. Load Bundle(2)
3. Shutdown karaf

It is evident that (2) is dependent on (1). While shutting down Karaf, Bundle(1) gets removed first, this results in the loss of in-flight messages as it cannot find its dependency and cannot process further.

I tried setting the start level of (1) both higher and lower than that of bundle(2). This did not help.

Also, I tried setting `org.apache.aries.blueprint.preemptiveShutdown=false` in `etc/config.properties`. This did not help as well.

Am I missing something here?

**-- EDIT 1 --**

After looking a bit over here and there, I found out that we can set a custom value for timeout in DefaultShutdownStrategy. So, as a workaround, I have done following:

```
<bean id="shutdownStrategy" class="org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy">
        <property name="timeout" value="1" />
</bean>
```

I understand that **this is not a clean and optimal way to do**. For the time being, it somehow helps me from losing a lot of in-flight messages.

But, any suggestion or feedback would be great.

**-- EDIT 2 -- Adding Blueprint File of Bundle 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.3.0"
           xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
           xsi:schemaLocation="
             http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd
             http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.3.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.3.0.xsd
             ">

    <!-- persistent-id for shared context -->
    <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="xxx.shared" update-strategy="none" >
        <cm:default-properties>
        ...
        </cm:default-properties>
    </cm:property-placeholder>

    <!--jms broker connection--> 
    <reference id="jmsProducerConnectionFactory" interface="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory" filter="(osgi.jndi.service.name=jms/xxx.producer)" availability="mandatory" />

    <bean id="xxx-producer" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsProducerConnectionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Source DB Reference -->
    <reference id="XDataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource" filter="(osgi.jndi.service.name=xxx-datasource)" availability="mandatory"/>

    <!-- Datawarehouse DB Reference -->
    <reference id="dw" interface="javax.sql.DataSource" filter="(osgi.jndi.service.name=xdb-datasource)" availability="mandatory"/>

    <bean id="prs" class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="XDataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="timestamp" class="org.library.shared.TimestampImplementation" destroy-method="synchronize" depends-on="dw">
        <argument index="0" ref="dw" />
        <argument index="2" value="Orders" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="shutdownStrategy" class="org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultShutdownStrategy">
        <property name="timeout" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <camelContext id="camel-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint" depends-on="timestamp">   
        <packageScan>
            <package>org.xyz.orders.routing</package>
        </packageScan>
    </camelContext>
</blueprint>
```

The other bundle is simply a collection of few classes (a shared library), which I have included as a maven dependency. There is no blueprint file for that bundle.

Due to organizational issues, I have used dummy names at some places.

Comment: Can you show the blueprint xml of your bundles?

Comment: Hi! thank you for your reply.I have updated my question with the contents of the blueprint file of a bundle. As a workaround, I have used shutdown strategy, but I feel that it's not the proper way to do it.
The other bundle is simply a collection of few classes (a shared library), which I have included as a maven dependency. There is no blueprint file for that bundle.

So, now my requirement is that this bundle(with Blueprint file) should shut down before the shared library bundle.
Thanks!